# AWS Quicksight : How to use parameter value inside SQL (data set) to render dynamic data on dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

There is a provision to pass value for quicksight parameters via URL. But how can I use the value of the parameter inside SQL (data set) to get dynamic data on dashboard?

For example:
QUERY as of now:

```
select * from CITYLIST;
```

Dashboard:

```
CITYLIST

city_name | cost_of_living
AAAAAAAAA | 20000
BBBBBBBBB | 25000
CCCCCCCCC | 30000
```

Parameter Created : cityName
URL Triggered : https://aws-------------------/dashboard/abcd123456xyz#p.cityName=AAAAAAAAA

Somehow I need to use the value passed in URL inside SQL so that I can write a dynamic query as below:
select * from CITYLIST where city_name = SomeHowNeedAccessOfParameterValue;

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also looking for same kind of solution.I have also checked for Parameter but it does not server the purpose. I want similar implementation you shown above

Answer (score 1):

QuickSight doesn't provide a way to access parameters via SQL directly.

Instead you should [create a filter from the parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-filtering-by.html) to accomplish your use-case.

This is effectively QuickSight's way of creating the `WHERE` clause for you.

This design decision makes sense to me. Though it takes filtering out of your control in the SQL, it makes your data sets more reusable (what would happen in the SQL if the parameter weren't provided?)

Comment: Yes Agree. But I want somehow it to be used in SQL, coz let's say There are 10k cities and I want 9k cities to be filtered on some single criteria (related to user). In this case I can send user via param and filter 9k cities in one go instead of sending 9k cities over parameter. Is there any brilliant approach?

Comment: @MohanNV that might be a job for row-level security: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/restrict-access-to-a-data-set-using-row-level-security.html

Comment: @mjpy3, yes, I've been through the above link already. But it requires multiple user/group creation and for each creation there is a cost involved. So can't afford to chose that option.

Comment: @MohanNV creating users doesn't cost anything, accessing with multiple users does. Also QuickSight throttles requests that it sees coming from the same user at the same time, so a "one user" system doesn't really work out if you're trying to support the "simultaneous users" use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [parameter, then control and then filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-filtering-by.html) ("Custom filter" -> "Use parameters").

If you select **Direct query** option and **Custom SQL query** for data set, then **SQL query will be executed per each visual change/update**.

The final query on DB side will look like [custom SQL query] + WHERE clause.

**For example**:

*Visual side*:
For control Control_1 selected values "A", "B", "C";

*DB side*:
[**Custom SQL** from data set] + '`WHERE column in ("A", "B", "C")`'

Quicksight builds a query for you and runs it on DB side.
This allows to reduce data sent over network.

Answer (score 1):

We have just released a new feature that supports this use case - Dataset Parameters in Amazon QuickSight. You can now create parameters in the dataset. map them to Analysis parameters, and use them to pass user's selection throughout actions, filters, controls, URLs, dynamic titles and descriptions in visuals, and propagate the selection to your custom SQL to optimize the load time of your visuals. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/dataset-parameters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes now it provides you to sql editor amd you can use it for the same purpose

l[image]

For full details please find the below reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-SQL-query.html

Comment: But where can I pass parameter into query. The query editor was there earlier too.